# Microsoft Graph Subscriptions - Not receiving calendar events notifications

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We are using a multitenant application.
We created a subscription to listen to calendar events for a particular user, but we are not receiving the notifications.

The user accepted the following scopes: `Calendars.Read Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.Read.Shared Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared offline_access User.Read.All`

When we call to POST `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions`
BODY:

```
{  
"resource": "/users/31c61efc-bc28-4552-9f0d-1a8735767c4e/calendars/AAMkAGRjZjY3OGRmLWU3MjAtNGExYy1hOTk0LTNkNjExOWVhZmYyNQBGAAAAAAD3yBF0B84VRJLe9CCZ4-ajBwDf5J1F10FqQ6VkC14neUWZAAAAAAEGAADf5J1F10FqQ6VkC14neUWZAABEL_2XAAA\u003d/events",  
"changeType": "created,updated,deleted",  
"clientState": "XXXXXX",  
"notificationUrl": "https://XXXXX.ngrok.io/notification/event",  
"expirationDateTime": "2019-05-31T14:42:08.651Z"
}
```

Then the notificationUrl is called and we receive the validation token:
`Validation: Testing client application reachability for subscription Request-Id: 9d020355-7589-4485-ba29-62d1ec899723`

But when we login into the `31c61efc-bc28-4552-9f0d-1a8735767c4e` account and update or create an event, no notification is beign sent.

If we call to GET `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions` the subscription is created:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#subscriptions",
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "b92d909e-b1b5-49b8-af54-74b7956d6565",
            "resource": "/users/31c61efc-bc28-4552-9f0d-1a8735767c4e/calendars/AAMkAGRjZjY3OGRmLWU3MjAtNGExYy1hOTk0LTNkNjExOWVhZmYyNQBGAAAAAAD3yBF0B84VRJLe9CCZ4-ajBwDf5J1F10FqQ6VkC14neUWZAAAAAAEGAADf5J1F10FqQ6VkC14neUWZAABEL_2XAAA=/events",
            "applicationId": "XXXX",
            "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
            "clientState": null,
            "notificationUrl": "https://XXXX.ngrok.io/notification/event",
            "expirationDateTime": "2019-05-31T14:42:08.651Z",
            "creatorId": "31c61efc-bc28-4552-9f0d-1a8735767c4e"
        }
    ]
}
```

Monitoring the ngrok calls, there is no failing call to the notification events endpoint.

Is there any console log we can verify to understand what the problem could be?

We tried to create subscriptions for different accounts with no success.
We also tried to subcribe to `/me/events`

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if it could the cause, but the calendar `id` to whom you're subscribing to is ending with `\u003d` instead of `=`. Encoding stuff. Might not be it, but for me its working well with this.

Hope its just this!
JS

Comment: I do receive some notifications sometimes, not always. For example, I was receiving notifications yesterday afternoon pretty consistently, but this morning..nothing. I haven't made any code changes. I didn't even restart the server.

Comment: I had the same issue as you mentioned @PrashantSaraswat. Yesterday night I received a bunch of notifications, but today nothing. Maybe is on Microsoft side.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a `ngrok` configuration issue? Is it possible you restarted it and now its exposing on a different url, therefore your subscription is no longer working?

Comment: @jstougas I'm pretty sure that I'm using the correct `ngrok` url. Now I changed to `Localtunnel` to be able to define a fixed host and to avoid to create different subscription each time I have to restart `ngrok`. Sometimes I receive the notifications, and sometimes just don't. I changed nothing on my side.

Comment: @jstougas I am pretty sure this is not an ngrok issue. Absolutely nothing changedon my side from one day to the next. I just stopped receiving notifications.